# Why would a WebService return nulls when the actual service returns data?

Tags: .net, xml, web-services, soap

I have a webservice (out of my control) that I have to talk to. I also have a packet-sniffer on the line, and the developers of the webservice aren't lying. I see data in the correct fields.

They are actually sending back all of the data that I requested. But the web-service code that is auto-generated from the WSDL file is giving me "null" as a value.

**UPDATE:** For clarification, the object returned is NOT null. The elements within the object are null. I don't know if that will help anyone or not. I'm totally stumped.

I used their WSDL file to generate my Web Reference. I checked my data types with the datatypes that the WSDL file has declared. And I used the code as listed below to perform the calls:

```
DT_MaterialMaster_LookupRequest req = new DT_MaterialMaster_LookupRequest();
req.MaterialNumber = "101*";
req.DocumentNo = "";
req.Description = "Pipe*";
req.Plant = "0000";

MI_MaterialMaster_Lookup_OBService srv = new MI_MaterialMaster_Lookup_OBService();

DT_MaterialMaster_Response resp = 
    srv.MI_MaterialMaster_Lookup_OB(new DT_MaterialMaster_LookupRequest[] { req });


// Note that the response here is ALWAYS null!!
Console.WriteLine(resp.Status);
```

The resp object is an actual object. It was generated properly. However, the Status and MaterialData fields are always null.

When I call the web service, I've placed a packet-sniffer on the line, and I can see that I've sent the following (linebreaks and indentions for my own sanity):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
 xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<soap:Body>
    <MT_MaterialMaster_Lookup 
        xmlns="http://MyCompany.com/SomeCompany/mm/MaterialMasterSearch">
        <Request xmlns="">
            <MaterialNumber>101*</MaterialNumber>
            <Description>Pipe*</Description>
            <DocumentNo />
            <Plant>0000</Plant>
        </Request>
    </MT_MaterialMaster_Lookup>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

The response that they send back SEEMS to be a valid response (linebreaks and indentions for my own sanity):

```
<SOAP:Envelope xmlns:SOAP='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'>
<SOAP:Header />
    <SOAP:Body>
        <n0:MT_MaterialMaster_Response
           xmlns:n0='http://MyCompany.com/SomeCompany/mm/MaterialMasterSearch'
           xmlns:prx='urn:SomeCompany.com:proxy:BRD:/1SAI/TAS4FE14A2DE960D61219AE:701:2009/02/10'>
        <Response>
            <Status>No Rows Found</Status>
            <MaterialData />
        </Response>
    </n0:MT_MaterialMaster_Response>
</SOAP:Body>
</SOAP:Envelope>
```

The status shows that it actually received data... but the resp.Status and resp.MaterialData fields are always null. What have I done wrong?

**UPDATE:**
The WSDL file is defined as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:p1="http://MyCompany.com/SomeCompany/mm/MaterialMasterSearch" name="MI_MaterialMaster_Lookup_OB" targetNamespace="http://MyCompany.com/SomeCompany/mm/MaterialMasterSearch" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">
  <wsdl:types>
    <xsd:schema xmlns="http://MyCompany.com/SomeCompany/mm/MaterialMasterSearch" 
        targetNamespace="http://MyCompany.com/SomeCompany/mm/MaterialMasterSearch" 
        xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
      <xsd:element name="MT_MaterialMaster_Response" type="p1:DT_MaterialMaster_Response" />
      <xsd:element name="MT_MaterialMaster_Lookup" type="p1:DT_MaterialMaster_Lookup" />
      <xsd:complexType name="DT_MaterialMaster_Response">
    <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element name="Status" type="xsd:string">
        <xsd:annotation>
          <xsd:appinfo source="http://SomeCompany.com/xi/TextID">d48d03b040af11df99e300145eccb24e</xsd:appinfo>
        </xsd:annotation>
      </xsd:element>
      <xsd:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="MaterialData">
        <xsd:annotation>
          <xsd:appinfo source="http://SomeCompany.com/xi/TextID">64908aa040a511df843700145eccb24e</xsd:appinfo>
        </xsd:annotation>
        <xsd:complexType>
          <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="MaterialNumber" type="xsd:string">
          <xsd:annotation>
            <xsd:appinfo source="http://SomeCompany.com/xi/TextID">64908aa140a511df848500145eccb24e</xsd:appinfo>
          </xsd:annotation>
        </xsd:element>
        <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="Description" type="xsd:string">
          <xsd:annotation>
            <xsd:appinfo source="http://SomeCompany.com/xi/TextID">64908aa240a511df95bf00145eccb24e</xsd:appinfo>
          </xsd:annotation>
        </xsd:element>
        <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="DocumentNo" type="xsd:string">
          <xsd:annotation>
            <xsd:appinfo source="http://SomeCompany.com/xi/TextID">64908aa340a511dfb23700145eccb24e</xsd:appinfo>
          </xsd:annotation>
        </xsd:element>
        <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="UOM" type="xsd:string">
          <xsd:annotation>
            <xsd:appinfo source="http://SomeCompany.com/xi/TextID">3b5f14c040a611df9fbe00145eccb24e</xsd:appinfo>
          </xsd:annotation>
        </xsd:element>
        <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="Hierarchy" type="xsd:string">
          <xsd:annotation>
            <xsd:appinfo source="http://SomeCompany.com/xi/TextID">64908aa440a511dfc65b00145eccb24e</xsd:appinfo>
          </xsd:annotation>
        </xsd:element>
        <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="Plant" type="xsd:string">
          <xsd:annotation>
            <xsd:appinfo source="http://SomeCompany.com/xi/TextID">d48d03b140af11dfb78e00145eccb24e</xsd:appinfo>
          </xsd:annotation>
        </xsd:element>
        <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="Procurement" type="xsd:string">
          <xsd:annotation>
            <xsd:appinfo source="http://SomeCompany.com/xi/TextID">d48d03b240af11dfb87b00145eccb24e</xsd:appinfo>
          </xsd:annotation>
        </xsd:element>
          </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
      </xsd:element>
    </xsd:sequence>
      </xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:complexType name="DT_MaterialMaster_Lookup">
    <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="Request">
        <xsd:annotation>
          <xsd:appinfo source="http://SomeCompany.com/xi/TextID">64908aa040a511df843700145eccb24e</xsd:appinfo>
        </xsd:annotation>
        <xsd:complexType>
          <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="MaterialNumber" type="xsd:string">
          <xsd:annotation>
            <xsd:appinfo source="http://SomeCompany.com/xi/TextID">64908aa140a511df848500145eccb24e</xsd:appinfo>
          </xsd:annotation>
        </xsd:element>
        <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="Description" type="xsd:string">
          <xsd:annotation>
            <xsd:appinfo source="http://SomeCompany.com/xi/TextID">64908aa240a511df95bf00145eccb24e</xsd:appinfo>
          </xsd:annotation>
        </xsd:element>
        <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="DocumentNo" type="xsd:string">
          <xsd:annotation>
            <xsd:appinfo source="http://SomeCompany.com/xi/TextID">64908aa340a511dfb23700145eccb24e</xsd:appinfo>
          </xsd:annotation>
        </xsd:element>
        <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="Plant" type="xsd:string">
          <xsd:annotation>
            <xsd:appinfo source="http://SomeCompany.com/xi/TextID">64908aa440a511dfc65b00145eccb24e</xsd:appinfo>
          </xsd:annotation>
        </xsd:element>
          </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
      </xsd:element>
    </xsd:sequence>
      </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:schema>
  </wsdl:types>
  <wsdl:message name="MT_MaterialMaster_Lookup">
    <wsdl:part name="MT_MaterialMaster_Lookup" element="p1:MT_MaterialMaster_Lookup" />
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="MT_MaterialMaster_Response">
    <wsdl:part name="MT_MaterialMaster_Response" element="p1:MT_MaterialMaster_Response" />
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:portType name="MI_MaterialMaster_Lookup_OB">
    <wsdl:operation name="MI_MaterialMaster_Lookup_OB">
      <wsdl:input message="p1:MT_MaterialMaster_Lookup" />
      <wsdl:output message="p1:MT_MaterialMaster_Response" />
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:portType>
  <wsdl:binding name="MI_MaterialMaster_Lookup_OBBinding" type="p1:MI_MaterialMaster_Lookup_OB">
    <binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" />
    <wsdl:operation name="MI_MaterialMaster_Lookup_OB">
      <operation soapAction="http://SomeCompany.com/xi/WebService/soap1.1" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" />
      <wsdl:input>
    <body use="literal" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" />
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
    <body use="literal" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" />
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:binding>
  <wsdl:service name="MI_MaterialMaster_Lookup_OBService">
    <wsdl:port name="MI_MaterialMaster_Lookup_OBPort" binding="p1:MI_MaterialMaster_Lookup_OBBinding">
      <address location="http://bxdwas.MyCompany.com/XISOAPAdapter/MessageServlet?channel=:SOAP_SND_Material_Lookup" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" />
    </wsdl:port>
  </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'd have to post the WSDL for me to be sure, but "Web Service Returns Null" almost always means there's a dispute about XML Namespaces - the service is sending you data in one namespace, and .NET is expecting a different namespace.

In this case, note that most of the response is in the default namespace, even though the wrapper element is in the `http://MyCompany.com/SomeCompany/mm/MaterialMasterSearch` namespace.

Comment: Great idea... I've bumped your answer beause it was a good shot. However, I'm able to fake a packet, and I've faked their packet and changed namespaces all over the place. This doesn't seem to be the problem. It's not crashing, and the object itself is NOT NULL. The items within the object are null.

Comment: @Jerry: I'll try to look at this in more detail over lunch - but I have to say that the WSDL does _not_ show the signs that usually indicate mixed namespaces. In the meantime, if you could look in your Reference.cs file and see which namespaces have been put on the elements, and compare with the XML, that would be good.

Comment: Spoke with developers and had them send me a new WSDL. (You'd swear I asked them to send government secrets). FINALLY got it, and wouldn't you know, it's different. Apparently each item is now an array of items, not a single item, thus why it was null... .NET couldn't determine the type so it left it null.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your service references are up to date.  This happens to us when the service WSDL changed but the references were not updated.